# How to redirect output from CMD window to file

Tags: windows, vbscript, io-redirection

I wrote the following VBScript in order to run commands from WIN XP on a Linux machine and redirect the output command to `out.txt` file (under `C:\`)

I don’t understand why output from the command window is not written to `out.txt` file.

What’s wrong with the line

```
Sh.Run "cmd /k  & CMD >> ""C:\out.txt""" , 1, True
```

My full VB script:

```
'TARGET_HOST  - Linux machine

Const TARGET_HOST = "18.20.183.99"
const PATH =  "cat /etc/hosts" 
const LOGIN = "root"
const PASS = " dingdong "
Const PLINKPATH="""C:\SPUTNIK\plink.exe"""

Set Sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

CMD = " echo y | " & PLINKPATH & " -ssh -pw " & PASS & LOGIN & "@" & " " & TARGET_HOST & " " & PATH 

Sh.Run "cmd /k  & CMD >> ""C:\out.txt""" , 1, True

Set Sh = Nothing
```

Comment: so what I need to fix in my code?

Answer (score 4):

VBScript doesn't expand variables inside strings. Change this:

```
Sh.Run "cmd /k  & CMD >> ""C:\out.txt""" , 1, True
```

into this:

```
Sh.Run "cmd /k " & CMD & " >> ""C:\out.txt""" , 1, True
```

On top of that your command is malformed. You need to put a space between password and username, and remove the space between `@` and hostname:

```
CMD = " echo y | " & PLINKPATH & " -ssh -pw " & PASS & " " _
  & LOGIN & "@" & TARGET_HOST & " " & PATH
```