# VBScript Carriage Returns

Tags: vbscript, windows-xp

I write the following VB script in order to run commands from WIN XP on Linux machine and redirect the output command to out.txt file ( under C:\ )

My VB script I print the /etc/hosts file from Linux machine in to out.txt file

Script works fine but I have one problem:

/etc/hosts file was printed in **out.txt** file with one long line  , in place of three lines

Example: (out.txt)

```
         127.0.0.1      localhost  19.20.183.99  MY_IP 10.10.10.10 LOOP
```

In place to print the following host file in **out.txt**

```
127.0.0.1      localhost
19.20.183.99  MY_IP
10.10.10.10 LOOP
```

MY VB script

```
Const TARGET_HOST = "19.20.183.99"
const PATH =  "cat /etc/hosts" 
const LOGIN = "root"
const PASS = " dgdgd "
Const PLINKPATH="""C:\dir1\plink.exe"""
Set Sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

CMD = " echo y | " &   PLINKPATH  & " -ssh -pw " & PASS & LOGIN & "@" & TARGET_HOST & " " & PATH 

Sh.Run "cmd /k" & CMD &  " > ""C:\out.txt""" , 1, True
```

Please advice what I need to fix in my VB script in order to print the correct hosts file ( line by line ) and not as one long line ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB sciprt + how redirect output from CMD window to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558796/vb-sciprt-how-redirect-output-from-cmd-window-to-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do a replace of lf (line feed) for lf and cr (carriage return). Linux only has LFs, where windows also requires the carriage return to show the extra line.

Alternatively, open the file in Notepad++ and you'll notice that the lines are printed line by line. (http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.4.5.html)

EDIT:
Try the following after you outputted the file to replace the line feeds (reference: [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/02/08/how-can-i-find-and-replace-text-in-a-text-file.aspx)):

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\out.txt", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, chr(10), chr(13) & chr(10))

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\out.txt", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
objFile.Close
```

Comment: please give me example?

Comment: By the way, if you are using a lot of files between *nix and windows, notepadd++ is a life saver, (showing only line feeds already like a new line, unlike normal notepad).

Comment: I update my script with your code , but still file has only one line -:(  [ I used the chr(10) .....

Comment: i just realize i switched the 10 and 13 chr's around. I've updated the answer to switch them to 13 first and then 10.